# Run luigi tasks in parallel

Tags: python, luigi

I have an application with several luigi tasks (I did not write that app). Now I want to introduce another task, in the middle of a process, which will monitor some AWS instances. This task, once started, should run until the end and it must run in parallel with other tasks. You can see picture in the link for better understanding.
[Link to the schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prnGb.jpg)
I looked in the documentation but I could not find solution. I am new with luigi and I probably missed something.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you missed anything. I don't think that luigi covers that use case. However, one thing you could do is have Task 3 require only Task 2, have Task 4 require task 2 instead of task 3, and have Task 3 continually run some code and monitor the output of Task 5 to know when it should close. It's not the prettiest, but it should work.

However, there are a couple of problems I can forsee (which is why it probably isn't supported by luigi). If you have enough Task 3's running, you might never complete the workflow, as Task 4 never gets run. That's why this isn't recommended as you are essentially creating hidden requirements that the dependency graph doesn't know about. Another issue is that Task 3 might never run until you are done with all of the Task 5's, in which case, it's useless.

One last idea I have is that instead of having Task 3 at all, at the end of Task 2 or beginning of task 4 you start a process on the scheduler node (using simply luigi.Task instead of an extension to make the work run on another node on the cluster). Then at the end of Task 5 you remove the process. There are some other edge cases you'll need to consider though, to make sure the process doesn't run too short or too long.

Good luck!